# Preventing Update of LastUsed in MetadataBag for specific Controller

Tags: symfony, session

I wrote an event listener for `kernel.request` to make me able to logout user automatically when he is idle for more than an amount of time.
I use this to calculate idle time:

```
$idle = time() - $this->session->getMetadataBag()->getLastUsed()
```

But I have a periodic Ajax request in my pages (for notification counts in pages) and they constantly change the `LastUsed` field of `MetadataBag` so Idle limit never reaches.
Is it possible to prevent a specific `Controller` (that ajax controller) to update session `LastUsed` ?
If yes, How?
If no, what else can I do to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how to prevent the update of `MetadataBag`'s `lastUsed`, but you can manually set the time for the user's last request, in the session and use it.
You can create a listener like below and make it listen to the `kernel.request` event, and in your other listener, get the data you store using this listener in the session instead of `$this->session->getMetadataBag()->getLastUsed()`.

```
public function listen(GetResponseEvent $event){
  // in your listeners main function
  $request = $event->getRequest();
  $route = $request->attributes->get('_route');
  if($route != 'your_ajax_check_route'){
    // update the session and etc.
    // retrieve what you store here in your other listener.
  }
}
```

Comment: Neat. You use the same listener to update last request time and to check if the idle limit has been reached. Answer upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

The feature you are talking about (prevent update session lastUsed) can't be done without some Symfony hacking which is unnecesary as you can simple create your own logic for this. For example you can create `KernelRequest listener` which will update last used session variable for all request except the one you will use to check how much time left too logout:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event): void
{
    if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
        return;
    }
    //$this->sessionMaxIdleTime is number from config parameter 
    //representing max idle time in seconds
    if ($this->sessionMaxIdleTime > 0) {
        $this->session->start();
        $time = time();

        $route = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route');
        //for all routes but one - checking how much time is left
        if ('session_check' !== $route) {
            //manual set lastUsed time 
            $this->session->set('manualLastUsedTime', $time);
        }
        $idleTime = $time - $this->session->get('manualLastUsedTime');
        if ($idleTime > $this->sessionMaxIdleTime) {
            $this->session->invalidate();
            $this->session->getFlashBag()->set('info', 'Logged out due to inactivity.');

            if ($event->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                $event->setResponse(new Response('Logged out due to inactivity.', Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN));
            } else {
                $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('login')));
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you can simple create method in some controller, which will be used by some ajax function to check how much time left to logout for example:

```
/**
 * @Route("/session/check", name="session_check", methods={"GET"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @param SessionInterface $session
 * @param int $sessionMaxIdleTime
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function checkSecondsToExpire(Request $request, SessionInterface $session, $sessionMaxIdleTime = 0): JsonResponse
{
    $idleTime = time() - $session->get('manualLastUsedTime');
    $secToExp = $sessionMaxIdleTime - $idleTime;
    return new JsonResponse(['secToExp' => $secToExp]);
}
```

Last piece is to make some check mechanism. It can be done as simple as starting some JS function in your base template. The parameter is in twig syntax and is from config (it is the same as `sessionMaxIdleTime` in `kernelRequest` listener):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SessionIdler.start({{ session_max_idle_time }});
    });
</script>
```

`SessionIdler.start` is just a function that runs some other function in specific interval (in this example it will run 1 minute before configured `sessionmaxIdleTime`):

```
function start(time) {
    checkSessionCounter = setInterval(checkSession, (time - 60) * 1000);
    isCheckSessionCounterRunning = true;
    // console.debug("checkSession will START in: " + (time - 60) + "s");
}
```

`checkSession` function make ajax request to our `session_check` route and depends on result it shows modal with proper information about too long inactivity. Modal can have a button or action when hiding, that will make another request to `session_extend` route (which can do nothing - it just need to be captured by `kernelRequest` listener to overwrite `manualLastUsedTime`)

This three pieces together creates a mechanism for notify user about too long inactivity without any influence on session metadataBag.